# Match substring in string on JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string x-category-2-deti. And i need check if 'x-category-deti' included in my string. How make this on native JS or jQuery.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Just include `.*` to match the intermediate chars.

```
/x-category\b.*-deti/.test(string);
```